# I sort of understand what a class is, but I don't really get when or how they're used

Tags: oop, class

I sort of get the idea behind a class I think, but I'm having a lot of trouble visualizing the way they would actually be used. I was thinking about it in the context of a game like Starcraft or Command and Conquer, where you have a class which would be your 'Terran Marine', and the objects associated with that class are all actual Terran Marine units you produce? Or would it be more like the class is 'units', and the objects are all the individual units you produce?

or am I looking at this in entirely the wrong way?

Comment: When you say "class" do you mean the general OOP term? Or some more specific usage in a certain language/platform/framework?

Answer (score 1):

You somewhat got it right. In OOP, everything concept is a class and every object is an instance. By your Starcraft example, the terran marine is a type of unit which itself is a class.

```
class Unit
{
    Unit();
    move();
    destroy();
}

class Marine : public Unit
{
    Marine();
    move();
    destroy();
    attack( Unit otherUnit );
}
```

This is just a basic layout of classes. You see some basic commands that are common to all units in the `Unit` class and the attack command which is introduced by the `Marine` class. Of course, it would be more correct to have another class `CombatUnit` (since some units in Starcraft are not combatant), but I hope you get the general idea.

A more extensive example is this:

```
interface Unit
{
    move();
    destroy();
}
class CombatUnit : public Unit
{
    attack(Unit target);
}
class HealerUnit : public Unit
{
    heal(Unit pacient);
}
class Marine : public CombatUnit
{
    Marine();
    move();
    destroy();
    attack(Unit target);
}
class Medic : public HealerUnit
{
    Medic();
    move();
    destroy();
    heal(Unit pacient);
}
```

Then you could have something like:

```
CombatUnit* marine = new Marine;
HealerUnit* medic = new Medic;
medic->heal(*marine);
marine->attack(*medic);
```

Comment: I don't think character classes in StarCraft would map to classes in code, though. Maybe "Unit" is as far down as it goes. The rest are probably just different property values and behaviour scripts.

Comment: Agreed, however I feel my example is good in terms of OOP. Leaving aside optimizations and design choices made by game developers, I think it illustrates the basic concepts pretty well.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that "objects" in the program very often do not match all that closely to "real-life" (game-world) objects in the domain the program is written for, but rather represent internal or more abstract concepts of a program. So these Animals and Cars examples are potentially misleading/misrepresentative.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is the right one. Think of classes as abstract things (typically nouns) that you have in the game. Objects are manifestations of these classes. So, in a game scenario, you can represent obstacles as a class and each obstacle becomes an object of that class (of course, various obstacles will be types of the original obstacle class).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite generic, since everything depends on the language you are using, but all the languages that use Oriented Object Programming have the concept of inheritance, implemented in different ways.

Inheritance means your class can extend from other class/es, inheriting all the properties from it and adding new ones.

For example:

- Class Unit, all the units in the game have some common attributes, like health, speed, etc.., so you can isolate all the common attributes in this class
- Class Terran Marine, extends the Unit Class (all Terran Marines are units, but Zergs also are units), adding new properties (special attack, etc) and defining the attributes for the Terran Marines units (speed = 10, health = 120)
- Finally you have the objects, which are instances of classes, you can have 2 instances of Terran Marines (you produced 2 instances), which have all the attributes defined in the Terran Marine class (which means they also have the ones from Unit class)